# I could not debug scala remote application on eclipse or IntelliJ IDEs

Tags: eclipse, scala, remote-debugging

I have scala server side application on eclipse IDE, I followed Remote configuration for that server side application on eclipse but nothing worked for me. Are there any suggestion to debug the scala application on eclipse, IntelliJ or other IDEs?

Comment: How are you running your application? I.e. did you specify the jvm xdebug command line parameter?

Comment: I gave the VM arguments on eclipse like as follows
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

Comment: I start the jetty server on SBT by giving command 
"container:start" and I have set the environment variable on windows machine like 
SBT_OPTS = "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"

Comment: Do you fork the JVM for the running process `container:start`, or does it run inside SBT JVM? If the former, you need to pass the debug parameters to the forked JVM.

Comment: Jetty Server runs inside the SBT JVM.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days, I got a way to debug the scala server side application on eclipse which is, create a test class to what scala class you want to debug. then put the break points on some method in scala class and run the created test class using "Debug as scala test file" on eclipse.